# How to convert any type of video in mp4

Tags: javascript, html, meteor, ffmpeg, meteor-blaze

I'm using meteor with blaze for development of web-app. I have used html 5 video tag for play video in browser. other types like mp4 and m4v is working fine in all browser but MOV format file is not play in any browser.

So I think to convert MOV to mp4 before upload.

Anyone have any idea about convert video before upload using js or meteor. OR any other way we can play MOV type video in any browser

Answer (score 1):

Using ffmpeg, you can first try

```
ffmpeg -i in.mov -c copy -movflags +faststart out.mp4
```

If the codecs aren't supported in MP4 or HTML5, run

```
ffmpeg -i in.mov -movflags +faststart out.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use [VLC media player][1]

[1]: http://www.videolan.org/vlc/ to convert the file. 
Click on File-> Select Convert/Save option.

Comment: I need code for convert mov to mp4 in meteor or js. Or provide an example if we can embed vlc player in web page.